# How do I install kernel headers for VMWare to match my running kernel (version 2.6.35-22-generic)

Tags: vmware-server, ubuntu-10.10

I am trying to install VMWare Server 1.0.6 , and have also tried VMWare server 2.0.2 BOTH 64 bit, on ubuntu 10.10 64 bit.

But i i keep getting this error:

```
What is the location of the directory of C header files that match your running
kernel? [/usr/src/linux/include] /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build/include/

The directory of kernel headers (version @@VMWARE@@ UTS_RELEASE) does not match
your running kernel (version 2.6.35-22-generic).  Even if the module were to
compile successfully, it would not load into the running kernel.
```

snaphot of stdout:

```
What is the location of the directory of C header files that match your running
kernel? [/usr/src/linux/include] /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build/include/


The directory of kernel headers (version @@VMWARE@@ UTS_RELEASE) does not match
your running kernel (version 2.6.35-22-generic).  Even if the module were to
compile successfully, it would not load into the running kernel.
```

in /usr/src, i have:

```
root@pandora:/usr/src# ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 2011-02-02 18:38 linux-headers-2.6.35-22
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 2011-02-02 16:25 linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic
```

and uname -a returns:

```
uname -a
Linux pandora 2.6.35-22-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:32:27 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How do i resolve this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating two symlinks will fix your problem:

```
ln -s /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build/include/generated/utsrelease.h /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build/include/linux/utsrelease.h
ln -s /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build/include/generated/autoconf.h /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build/include/linux/autoconf.h
```

I found the solution on [it-psycho.de](http://translate.google.de/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://www.it-psycho.de/2010/08/20/vmware-server-2-0-2-mit-linux-kernel-2-6-34/) and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link:
http://hootbah.zingzam.com/2006/12/13/vmware-on-debian-etch-kernel-2-6-18-3/

I remember similar solution in early version of VMware server.
It worked for me.

Comment: version.h has #define UTS_RELEASE "2.6.35-22-generic" 
#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE 132643
#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) (((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c)) but error is: What is the location of the directory of C header files that match your running
kernel? [/usr/src/linux/include]  /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build/include 

The path "/lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build/include" is a kernel header file
directory, but it does not contain the file "linux/autoconf.h" as expected.  
This can happen if the kernel has never been built, or if you have invoked the 
"make mrproper" command in your